# What does it mean when a question is closed as a duplicate by the "community" robot?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicate-questions

Question [57192](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/57192/could-ted-cruz-or-another-sitting-senator-be-appointed-to-be-a-scotus-judge) was deleted as a duplicate by a single named user and a robot named "[community](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)".   While there is some overlap between the old question (on [qualifications in general](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13392/what-requirements-are-there-for-becoming-a-supreme-court-justice)), I think the new (today) question has answers that more directly address the OP's question.

The user page for "community" summarizes the bot saying it does things like:
I do things like

- Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
- Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
- Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
- Own suggested edits from anonymous users
- Remove abandoned questions
  on the server farm

Is the bot behaving as intended by closing a question the same day it was opened by the vote of a single human?

Answer (score 8):

This behaviour is explained on [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276472/461068):

> If you vote to close your own question as a duplicate of something else... and refresh the page, you'll see the "your question may already have an answer here" banner. Clicking the "that solved my problem!" button on that banner results in Community instantly closing your question as a duplicate.

Essentially, the vote that says "Community" was actually the OP agreeing with divibisan's close-vote and closing the question themselves.